# yum or dnf update with `--skip-broken` on just one repo?

Tags: centos, yum, dnf

Is there a way to run

```
yum update --skip-broken
```

Such that only missing packages from one repository are skipped? As a third party that distributes RPM packages we would like our broken packages to not hold back a `yum update`, but we don't want to adversely affect mainline CentOS's yum behavior?

Comment: Couldn't you just use `... disablerepo=<that one repo> ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution, is to run the third party repo out of cycle.

1. Mark the third party repo as disabled. Then it won't run in `yum update`.
2. Update that repo with `yum update --skip-broken --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="myRepo"`.